# Securing SSL certificate and private key in apache server?

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, hashicorp-vault

Normally apache web sever needs SSL certificates to load from file. This makes certificates to store in apache webserver disk. Is this considered as security risk ? Is there set of guidelines to secure these certificates ? I have client which thinks this is a risk and I want to prove him otherwise or give a solution. So far i have not come across with good solution. Even we use solution like HashiCorp vault still the certificates needs to be given to apache server disk. Any suggestions or guidelines to secure this ssl certificate or any best practices for storing ssl certificate in secure manner is very helpful.

Comment: There are no risks to host the certificate on the server. It's not a password...

Answer (score 0):

**Approach: 1(Older)** Maintain the certificates in disk and secure the directory which holds the certificates. Following steps is an option to secure certificates in disk.

1. Change permission of certificates directory to '700' to restrict other users of server can not access(for read/write/delete) the files
2. Change permission of apache bin and conf directories which holds the path for certificates and start up scripts. This also to be restricted from other users
3. Disable sftp & scp for apache user to avoid sending any file outside the server

**Approach:2** Integration with HSM Hardware to generate and store SSL certificates and improve performance by offloading encryption and decryption  through HSM.
There are few market vendors available in market to integrate Apache Web server with HSM like Luna HSM by Thales (https://cpl.thalesgroup.com/resources/encryption/apache-http-server-luna-integration-guide), nCipher HSM, AWS CloudHSM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Private key is what you need to protect; not certificates. Best way to protect a Private key is by using a Hardware device such as a Smart-Card, USB Token or a Hardware Security Module (HSM).

A digital certificate contains the public key which is mostly distributed publicly. Even if someone gets it, there's hardly anything they could do with it.